# Форма регистраци React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

есть данный код:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
 
class UserForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
var name = props.name;
var result_n = this.validateName(toString(name, 0));
var l_name = props.l_name;
var result_l = this.validateName(toString(l_name, 1));
var m_name = props.m_name;
var result_m = this.validateName(toString(m_name, 2));
var password = props.password;
var copy_password = props.copy_password;
var result_pass = this.validatePassword(
toString(password),
toString(copy_password)
);
var login = props.login;
var result_login = this.validateLogin(toString(login));
var email = props.email;
var result_email = this.validateEmail(toString(email));
var phone = props.phone;
var result_phone = this.validatePhone(toString(phone), toString(email));
 
this.state = {
name: "Введите имя",
result_n: "",
l_name: "Введите фамилию",
result_l: "",
m_name: "Введите отчество",
result_m: "",
password: "",
result_pass: "",
copy_password: "",
login: "",
result_login: "",
email: "...@mail.ru",
result_email: "",
phone: "+7",
result_phone: ""
};
 
this.onChangeName = this.onChangeName.bind(this);
this.onChangeNameL = this.onChangeNameL.bind(this);
this.onChangeNameM = this.onChangeNameM.bind(this);
this.onChangeLogin = this.onChangeLogin.bind(this);
this.onChangeEmail = this.onChangeEmail.bind(this);
this.onChangePhone = this.onChangePhone.bind(this);
this.onChangePassword = this.onChangePassword.bind(this);
this.onChangePasswordCopy = this.onChangePasswordCopy.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}
 
//пусто - валидация успешна
//строка с ошибкой - валидация не успешна
validateName(str, index) {
var fio = ["имя", "фамилию", "отчество"];
if (str == "") return " Введите " + fio[index];
return "";
}
 
//проверка паролей
validatePassword(password, copy) {
if (password != "" && password == copy && password.length > 6) return "";
else return "введите пароль повторно";
}
 
validateLogin(login) {
if (login.length < 6) return "логин меньше 6-ти символов";
else return "";
}
 
validateEmail(field) {
if (field == "") return "";
else if (
!(field.indexOf(".") > 0 && field.indexOf("@") > 0) ||
/[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/.test(field)
)
return "Электронный адрес имеет неверный формат.\n";
return "";
}
 
validatePhone(phone, email) {
if (phone == "" && email == "") return "введите email или номер телефона";
else return "";
}
 
onChangePhone(e) {
var val = e.target.value;
var res = this.validatePhone(val);
this.setState({ phone: val, result_phone: res });
}
 
onChangeEmail(e) {
var val = e.target.value;
var res = this.validateEmail(val);
this.setState({ email: val, result_email: res });
}
 
onChangeLogin(e) {
var val = e.target.value;
var res = this.validateLogin(val);
this.setState({ login: val, result_login: res });
}
 
onChangePassword(e) {
var val = e.target.value;
this.setState({ password: val });
}
 
onChangePasswordCopy(e) {
var val = e.target.value;
var res = this.validatePassword(this.state.password, val);
this.setState({ copy_password: val, result_pass: res });
}
 
onChangeName(e) {
var val = e.target.value;
var res = this.validateName(val, 0);
this.setState({ name: val, result_n: res });
}
 
onChangeNameL(e) {
var val = e.target.value;
var res = this.validateName(val, 1);
this.setState({ l_name: val, result_l: res });
}
 
onChangeNameM(e) {
var val = e.target.value;
var res = this.validateName(val, 2);
this.setState({ m_name: val, result_m: res });
}
 
handleSubmit(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var ris =
"name: " +
this.state.name +
" l_name: " +
this.state.l_name +
" m_name: " +
this.state.m_name +
" password: " +
this.state.password +
" copy: " +
this.state.copy_password +
" login: " +
this.state.login +
"email: " +
this.state.email +
"phone: " +
this.state.phone;
 
var res =
this.state.result_n +
this.state.result_m +
this.state.result_l +
this.state.result_pass +
this.state.result_login +
this.state.result_email +
this.state.result_phone;
 
if (res == "") window.open("public/newsite.html");
else alert(ris);
}
 
render() {
return (
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
<p>
<label>Имя:</label>
<br />
<input
type="text"
value={this.state.name}
onChange={this.onChangeName}
/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Фамилия:</label>
<br />
<input
type="text"
value={this.state.l_name}
onChange={this.onChangeNameL}
/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Отчество:</label>
<br />
<input
type="text"
value={this.state.m_name}
onChange={this.onChangeNameM}
/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Логин:</label>
<br />
<input
type="text"
value={this.state.login}
onChange={this.onChangeLogin}
/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Пароль:</label>
<br />
<input
type="password"
value={this.state.password}
onChange={this.onChangePassword}
/>
</p>
<p>
<label>Повторите пароль:</label>
<br />
<input
type="password"
value={this.state.copy_password}
onChange={this.onChangePasswordCopy}
/>
</p>
<p>
<label>email:</label>
<br />
<input
type="text"
value={this.state.email}
onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
/>
</p>
<p>
<label>номер телефона:</label>
<br />
<input
type="text"
value={this.state.phone}
onChange={this.onChangePhone}
/>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
);
}
}
 
export default function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
<h3>Страница регистрации</h3>
<UserForm />,
</div>
);
}
```

требуется переписать на функциональные компоненты
вроде должно выглядеть как

```
<form>
<Login/>
<Password/>
....
</form>
```

Как возможно обработать такую форму?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял твой вопрос, тебе нужно воспользоваться подъёмом состояния. Это хорошо отражено в [документации](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#lifting-state-up).

В общих чертах тебе нужно вынести все элементы формы по компонентам, далее создать обработчик событий на изменение состояния. После передавать в качестве props дочерниму элементу те свойства, с которыми он будет работать и повесить твой обработчик событий на нужные input'ы.
Далее, форма обрабатывается как обычно, так как все свойства у тебя уже выставлены.

Примерная реализация:

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event){
        this.props.ChangeHandler(event)
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <input placeholder="input prop" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
        )
    }
}


class ParentComponent extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state={
            prop:''
        }
        this.changeHandler = this.changeHandler.bind(this)
    }

    changeHandler(event){
        this.setState({[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <ChildComponent prop={this.state.prop} changeHandler={this.changeHandler}/>
        )
    }
}
```